# NVidia and Intel in same Laptop: which card is used?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel

I'm trying to get my graphics card working in my Dell Mobile Precision 5510, which should be an NVidia Quaddro M1000M. The machine also has Intel graphics.

If I run `lspci`, I get, among other things,

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 191b (rev 06)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GLM [Quadro M1000M] (rev a2)
```

Then, sometimes, after a few seconds, the machine freezes.

From the output of `lspci`, it appears the machine has both an Intel graphics card, and an NVidia one (M1000M) as expected.
This being a laptop, I don't have separate adaptors, so I don't know how outputs are switched, but I'd like to make sure I'm using the NVidia card.

I installed the NVidia drivers but X was just a blank screen.
I'm reasonably happy with the Nouveau drivers, but I cannot confirm that the correct graphics card is being used. The laptop was delivered with Ubuntu 14.04 has has never run anything else.

`glxinfo` gives me the following:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Skylake Halo GT2 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.5.9
```

This sounds like the Intel card is being used. Is there a setting somewhere I could check? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two weeks of fiddling around and getting nowhere, I finally got the Nvidia card working with the NVidia drivers.
The issue is that I originally tried to install the Nvidia drivers with the Ubuntu software installer (don't do this) which was originally happily using the Intel drivers. This didn't work, and several reboots later it has removed the Intel option and was apparently using the Nouveau drivers on the Intel card - a configuration I'm not sure is even possible. My system was immensely unstable in this configuration and would lock up with `lspci` or when using 3D graphics.
I went through a lot of steps in order to fix this, and I don't really know what worked.

Get rid of whatever's there:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get purge nouveau*
```

Install the Intel driver. For some reason this uninstalls a load of stuff, such as wine. Can install it again later so don't worry.

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

I never explicitly uninstalled this (`apt-get purge intel*` is way too dangerous because of all the other Intel stuff) so presumably the Intel drivers are still there.

Add some respositories:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Install NVidia drivers and bumblebee:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-364
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic
```

This didn't work at first. I've no idea why. X would either not start, or keep returning me to the log-in screen. I tried replacing `lightdm` with `gdm`, that didn't work at all, so I went back to `lightdm`. Finally had one last try with the above and it worked. I can even use the `nvidia-settings` app to change to the Intel card.
Only problem is that I have a 4k screen on a 15" laptop. Most software doesn't scale properly. I can't run 1920x1080 anymore with the NVidia card for some odd reason (it runs in the centre of the screen with a massive black border) but it works with the Intel card ok.
I hope this helps somebody, but beware that hybrid graphics (on laptops) can be a complete pain to get working.

Answer (score 0):

As you have hybrid graphics, you need to have the proprietary NVIDIA drivers and Optimus support installed to use the NVIDIA graphics adapter and to switch between both graphics.

To check whether you are using the intel or the NVIDIA graphics open a terminal and execute :

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

The output from this command will give you an information which will be something like this :

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)  
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501  
Kernel driver in use: i915  

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)  
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501  
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

When it shows `Kernel driver in use: nvidia`, you are using the NVIDIA graphics adapter.

When you want to switch to the intel card - open NVIDIA X Server Settings -> PRIME Profiles.

If this for whatever reason doesn't work, you should install the latest official NVIDIA drivers.

Open a terminal and execute the following commands :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

**Update addressing your comment that you still cannot use the NVIDIA adapter properly :**

Use another method to install the drivers ... but first remove all installed NVIDIA software.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password and then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now reinstall the drivers 361.42 supporting the NVIDIA Quadro M1000M.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password and then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Note : Set a <kbd>Space</kbd> between the last character in the `linux` line and `nouveau.modeset=0`.

Comment: If I follow those instructions to install the NVidia drivers, I get to the unity login screen. But after logging in, screen just goes blank and then back to the log-in screen. Is there a way to get the Nouveau drivers to use the card?

Comment: I think systemd ignores nomodeset in the grub config.